# label of log y-axis: 1000 instead of 1e+03?

Tags: r, algorithm, graphics, statistics

I've a problem concerning construction of log y-axis in a graphic.

How can I manage that the units/numbers of my log y-axis aren't shown in

```
1e+03, 1e+04, 1e+05 etc....
```

But only in regular Arabic numbers (1000, 10000, 100000)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the axis (by setting `yaxt = "n"`) and then re-format it properly:

```
plot((1:100)^3, log = "y", yaxt = "n")
axis(2, format(c(1,10,100)^3, scientific=FALSE))
```

This was [asked before on R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/06/7640.html).

Comment: I suggest using axis(2, format(axTicks(2,log=TRUE), scientific=FALSE)) in the second line. Then it's less "human depend".

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you just don't like the look of 1e+03 scientific notation, the [sfsmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfsmisc/index.html) package has the `axTexpr()` function to format axis labels in a * 10^k notation.

```
library(sfsmisc)
example(axTexpr)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, the original poster wanted to get rid of the scientific notation of the labels. I had the same problem and found out this one works for that purpose (without using package sfsmisc from Kevin's answer, which I did not try):

```
plot((1:100)^3, log = "y", yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at=axTicks(2,log=TRUE), labels=format(axTicks(2, log=TRUE), scientific=FALSE))
```

Answer (score -3):

This is rather late, but I was searching for the same solution.  What I did (by searching, trial and error) is:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d') # shows 1 instead of 10^0 etc
```

and later, in the plot creating process:

```
ax = subplot(111) # ie one plot, but need to refer to it as 'ax'
semilogy(x,y)
```

and just before show(),

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
```

There may be unnecessary bits here, as I'm a rank Python newbie.

Comment: Your code is Python but the tags show that the desired programming language is R.